# iPad app closes after 2 seconds, memory issue?

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

I made a magazine iPad app so you can scroll through different slides to the left, right, down and up. It's all ready and accepted by the iTunes app store. Problem is, if someone downloads the app it closes directly after 1 seconds of loading.

Weird part is that i installed the app trough xCode and all works without any problems. My guess is that the app takes too much memory. I made a screenshot of the memory instrument:

[image: Memory instrument]

But how can i release a Srollview if it must be loaded all the time?

Hope someone could push me in the right direction!

Comment: Where are all those small mallocs coming from ?

Comment: when you install your app via Xcode, try using the **release** build config instead of debug, it will be identical to the one you submit to AppStore.

Comment: @Paul, i have no idea! The app loads a total of 30 SubScrollviews with full resolution images, maby that's the problem? Cant i release some views?

Comment: @Owen, tried that, still works :S

Comment: @JoeyT I just downloaded your app and tested it on my iPad, it worked without any problem. Where did you get the "close after 2 seconds" complaint? If it crash on your own device (or your friend's device), try plug it into your computer, and grab the crash log from Xcode Organizer.

Comment: Does the app support earlier OS's?  Could there be calls to 6.x libraries from 5.x devices?

Comment: @Owen Wow, thanks! But this makes me even more confused! People complain that the app closes right when they click the app, so it comes up and after 1 sec it closes during the loading screen. But if i connect that ipad on my iMac and run it trough xCode meterials it works fine :/

Comment: @Mike M Not that i know off, it's all really basic programming. The app is supported for 5.1 and higher. I will try to post it as a 6.0 app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested your app on my iPad2 with iOS 5.1.1, and it crash with the following message:

```
OxygenEvents[97151] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x375c388f 0x31638259 0x375c3789 0x375c37ab 0x309de54d 0x309de6bb 0x309de423 0x3096f001 0x308dd3c7 0x307bac59 0x30730c17 0x10d5d5 0x30730c8b 0x109beb 0x30730c8b 0x3072f461 0x30721e87 0x307927d5 0x10960b 0x3072fcab 0x307297dd 0x306f7ac3 0x306f7567 0x306f6f3b 0x3771322b 0x37597523 0x375974c5 0x37596313 0x375194a5 0x3751936d 0x3072886b 0x30725cd5 0x10944f 0xf0050)
```

It is because you use "Autolayout" in your Interface Builder files (nib / xib files), which is an iOS 6.0 only feature.

To solve this, either disable Autolayout in all your xib files like this:

[image: uncheck Autolayout]

or simply make your app iOS 6.0 only by setting deployment target as iOS 6.0

Comment: Dude, you are a legend! Could you tell me how you get that error message? And last question; my app is using 200mb memory!? HOW!? :P Thanks again

Comment: it was found in Xcode Organizer > Devices > (my device name) > Console. And also a crash report in the Device Logs. From your screenshot live bytes = 2.70 MB, where did you found 200 MB ?

Comment: Nice thanks, if i Profile the app in xCode > Materials and choose the 'Activity Monitor' it says the app uses 200MB of memory. I made a screenshot: http://tinypic.com/r/b7xtf9/6

Comment: hmm, guess I need to take a look at your code before I can give any useful suggestions on that.